# How to check if user is authorized Angular + PHP

Tags: php, angular

I configured authentication using Angular and PHP.
But if page is reloaded - user have to enter login and password again.
Because after reloading - angular's variable "IsLoggedIn" is set to false.

Is there a way how to pass session data from php side to angular without additional ajax request to server?

Because firstly php framework is loaded and then it shows a view with html and angular scripts.

Comment: Look into [token based authentication](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/298973) and store the token in the browser session storage. If the browser if refreshed, fetch the token and check it's validity.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by jwt or any other token base authentication.